# Php spl_autoload_register doesn't work

Tags: php, autoload

I can't run a php project under debian with autoload. My project is like this :

```
myproject
- config
       autoload.php
   - src
      - Project
          router.php
   index.php
```

autoload.php :

```
<?php

// Your custom class dir
define('SRC_DIR', './src/');

// Add your class dir to include path
set_include_path(SRC_DIR);

// You can use this trick to make autoloader look for commonly used   "My.class.php" type filenames
spl_autoload_extensions('.php');

// Use default autoload implementation
spl_autoload_register();

?>
```

index.php :

```
<?php

// Chargement des classes via le namespace
require_once('./config/autoload.php');

$router = new \Project\Router();
```

router.php :

```
<?php
namespace Project;

class Router {
```

And when I try to go to index.php, I have this error :

> PHP Fatal error:  spl_autoload(): Class Project\Router could not be
>   loaded in /var/www/html/exophp/index.php

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the directory "Project" it must be called "project". After it works !